# MissingPluginException in flutter in release mode android

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

Many plugins aren't working in flutter when you try to build a apk in release mode , but these plugins are working perfectly in debug mode

Some recomend changing the gradle version to 3.5 , but sometimes the plugins used may not be compatible with the same like `file_picker_cross`

Others recomend using `--no-shrink` option while building the apk i.e `flutter build apk --release --no-shrink`

None of that solutions worked for me , i found this solution burried in a github issue conversation

Check the solution below

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the recent proguard rules in flutter is ejecting the plugins which arent registering properly

In your project's `app/build.gradle`

change

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

to

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

The added extra 2 lines seems to skip the proguard rules part thereby saving your from the nightmare , this is just a temporary work around , there might be a fix soon from flutter

Ofcourse this skips the proguard optimization , but atleast the code works now ;)

I have been wasting my time for almost 6 hours without knowing the solution ,so I am posting it here for others

Comment: Works! Thanks  Saved me a few hours i can spent on my couch!

Comment: That's a real time saver!